# Docusign Custom Button Error: List has no rows for assignment to SObject

Tags: docusignapi

Custom button code:

```
`{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_JavaScript")}

var rc = GetRelContentIDs("{!Contact.Id}");
var CCTM = 'Client~Signer';
var CRL='Email~{!User.Email};Role~Client;FirstName~{!User.FirstName};LastName~{!User.LastName};SignNow~1';

window.location.href = "/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_CreateEnvelope?DSEID=961202FA-36C6-4A9A-B061-EDC7BE6C8B07&SourceID={!Contact.Id}&rc="+rc+"&CCTM="+CCTM+"&CRL="+CRL;`
```

Visualforce error:

```
List has no rows for assignment to SObject
Error is in expression '{!CreateEnvelopeRecord}' in component <apex:page> in page dsfs:docusign_createenvelope:(dsfs)

An unexpected error has occured. Your solution provider has been notified. (dsfs)
```

I have checked the permissions suggested by docusign and nothing has changed.

Any advice/help would be HUGELY appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: How about formatting your code to make it a little easier to read?

Answer (score 1):

The script is failing because DocuSign envelope Id  has been set to 961202FA-36C6-4A9A-B061-EDC7BE6C8B07. The DSIED should be set to ‘0’ by default.
Set `DSIED=0` and the script should work:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_JavaScript")}

var rc = GetRelContentIDs("{!Contact.Id}");
var CCTM = 'Client~Signer';
var CRL='Email~{!User.Email};Role~Client;FirstName~{!User.FirstName};LastName~{!User.LastName};SignNow~1';

window.location.href = "/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_CreateEnvelope?DSEID=0&SourceID={!Contact.Id}&rc="+rc+"&CCTM="+CCTM+"&CRL="+CRL;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set the DSEID=0 then it does not populate the template with the Client data which is what we are trying to do.
How do you get the Sign Now custom button to work.